# Simulator For Blackberry for Windows PC?

Tags: mobile, blackberry-simulator

Is there any single software that can be used to test the website designed for all blackberry mobile devices. In Blackberry website, they have given different simulators for each phone, we would like to know if there is any one software that an be used to test all the blackberry devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/index.shtml

Just click on "Download a device simulator" and you should be good to go!